# Is there a way to pick System.out or System.err messages when java program is executed using shell script

Tags: java, bash, shell

I needed to execute java class third party from shell script. When exception occurs, they are writing error message with System.err as per requirement. Now, when i executed the class in shell, i want to get that error message. I cannot get complete message in standard output and search for this message as its a big script and there are lot of messages. Is there a way to capture that specific System.err printed in java when i executed it in shell. ?Just let me know, if the problem is not clear enough.

Comment: try looking at Process Builder in java

Comment: I guess you just want to redirect stderr to a file? To do that, add `2>error.out` to your command, to redirect stderr to a file called `error.out`.

Comment: Hi the file redirect idea that you have works fine. Can i redirect it to a variable.? i need to execute the command in perl. So, i need to execute shell command that redirects stderr to variable.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it clear whether you're asking about executing a command in the shell, or from perl. [This section of the Perl docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command%3f) may be useful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pick your java application (or whatever program for that matter) standard error in a variable while discarding its standard output, you can use this shell construction:

```
var=$(java MyApplication 2>&1 1>/dev/null)
```

If you don't want to discard the standard output, you can redirect it to a file instead of `/dev/null`, or redirect it to your terminal emulator using `/dev/tty`.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this-

[How to print an error message to standard error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197737/how-to-print-an-error-message-to-standard-error)

I think the best answer to that question answers your question as well.